# Qualtrics Storing Text Input to Embedded Data by Creating New Buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, qualtrics

I've been struggling with this for a long time and finally have half a solution but not the rest.

Basically, I need Qualtrics respondents to enter a number input into a textbox inline, and I want to store that input as Embedded Data.

So far, in the html of the Qualtrics page, I have

```
Enter data here: <input type="text" id="myText" value=" ">
<input type="submit" value="Confirm" onclick="formdata()"/>

<script>
function formdata(){
var questionanswer= document.getElementById("myText").value;
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("Q1input", questionanswer);
}
</script>
```

This works fine. It creates the text box where they can enter "myText," and then it stores this as Embedded Data Q1input, which I can then access later. However, it's annoying because they have to click this "Confirm" button I created and then leave the page using the normal Qualtrics Next Page button. I did this because I couldn't get it to work at all by running this when the Qualtrics Next Button was clicked, so I had to make it run on my own button.

I've tried to disable the Next Page buttons using the disableNextButton and clickNextButton Qualtrics code, but I don't know where to put it. I can disableNextButton by putting the code in the addOnload portion, but I can't seem to get clickNextButton to run in the `formdata` function.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I don't really know JavaScript; I'm just trying to pick this up to run a survey.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to handle this is actually just to call your function any time the text entry field changes. Since Qualtrics includes PrototypeJS, you can use the following:

```
Enter data here: <input type="text" id="myText" value=" ">

<script>
function formdata(){
var questionanswer= document.getElementById("myText").value;
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("Q1input", questionanswer);
}

$('myText').observe('change', formdata());
</script>
```

Two thoughts here:

1. You should be including your script in the JavaScript section of your question, rather than the html edditor. It belongs in the addOnReady Section.

   Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnReady(function()
   {
   function formdata(){
       var questionanswer= document.getElementById("myText").value;
       Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("Q1input", questionanswer);
   }

   $('myText').observe('change', formdata());
   });
2. You could achieve the same effect by using a text entry question type in Qualtrics, then using piped-text to add it to the embedded data field in your survey flow.